# How can we include json formt data inside Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

How can we include json formt data inside Eclipse ??

Please see the below

```
String responserecivied ="{"dummyuser":{"Number":1,"CUSID":1}}";
```

When i included the above in Eclipse , i am getting compilation Errors

Its displaying Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens

Please tell me how can i include this in Eclipse .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a preference you can set in eclipse to make pasting into text easier

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape your double quotes

```
 String responserecivied ="{\"dummyuser\":{\"Number\":1,\"CUSID\":1}}";
```

Comment: Thanks Shyam , is there any setting that should be done inside Eclipse to achive this ?? because if its a large json then it will be very tough to do this manually . Any suggestions you have ??